# string split delimiter in bash returns double the size

Tags: bash, split, delimiter

The following bash script returns 4 while it should be 2 that is 2 IPS.

```
#!/bin/bash

STR="1.1.1.1***2.2.2.2"
IFS="***" read -ra IPArray <<< "$STR"
echo ${#IPArray[@]}
```

Comment: Read the Bash manual on [Word Splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) which covers the operation of `$IFS` in some detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IFS indicates separating characters, not a string. `IFS="***"` means * or * or *.

So you can modify it without IFS:

```
STR="1.1.1.1***2.2.2.2"
STR2=$(echo $STR | tr '*' ' ')
read -ra IPArray <<< "$STR2"
echo ${#IPArray[@]}
```

Comment: tr doesn't replace strings. `tr '*' ' '` is enough

Answer (score 1):

IFS treats each character as a delimiter.
https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS
That's why you are getting the array size as 4 in your code.
You should go for regexp to use string as IFS.